# Can someone help me identify this weed?

Tags: identification, weeds

[image]
It’s not a fuzzy weed like a geranium. Smooth leaves, with a citrusy smell when rubbed.

Answer (score 3):

That appears to be a hardy perennial *Geranium* variety, one of the true cranesbill Geraniums (unlike Pelargoniums). Many varieties of *Geranium*, such as 'Wargrave's Pink', have smooth leaves. Leave it alone, unless you don't want it growing where it is - you might be able to identify it fully once it flowers later on. It's not a 'weed' as such, although the accepted definition of 'weed' is simply a plant that's growing where you don't want it.

Comment: Yes I Googled Cranesbill and so far it appears to be exactly same plant. I am so happy whenever an opportunity arises to meet yet another “weed” to add to my meals (I love bitter foods as a side dish) and for medicinals or for nice scents I can offer to my deities to enjoy on my home altar (Hare Krishna).  Here in southern U.S. most the weeds in my garden are edibles and all are useful in some way. I may even retire from active gardening and just harvest them.  I got wild rabe, purslane, lambsquarter, henbit, cleavers, golden rod, cattails...  Bamboo, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Given that the geranium has a citrus smell, I'll identify it as Geranium x cantabrigiensis, either the basic hybrid or the 'Biokovo' cultivar. If it's Biokovo, it will bloom with a pale pink flower; if the basic hybrid, the flowers will be magenta. I find Biokovo to be a nice groundcover, spreading stoloniferously rather than rhizomatously, which means that it's easy to kill if you don't like it. The leaves in both spring and fall are scarlet. It's not a rampant spreader, either - maybe a foot or so a year once established.

Comment: Yes, I’ll check for those flowers. I really appreciate your help, Jurp! Hare Krishna

Answer (score 0):

This is possibly a species of anemone. The reason for this is that the plant form is a cluster of basal leaves with long leaf stems; it does not seem to be producing a tall main branching stalk which will carry the flowers. Possibly it will produce one later. Some anemones are known for their scent, for example the musky scent of [*Anemone nemorosa*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anemone_nemorosa). Of course all will be clearer when the flower appears, as it certainly will given the nice healthy appearance of the leaves.

Comment: Thank you Colin for your input. I’m letting an eye on them waiting for flowers 

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a cutleaf geranium, they are all over my yard and alley for the last couple years. Seem to have spread like wildfire. Sprayed lawn with crossbow and it knocked them out. Eugene, Or.